# Getting randomly error of org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json, jakarta-ee

Hi i am getting this JsonException sometimes... why this happen can any body solve this problem below is my code.

```
  public int getResult(String name, double lat, double lon) {
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String query = URLEncoder.encode(name, "utf-8");

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://00004rl.rcomhost.com/demo/?json=get_dealing&dev=1&store_name=" + query + "&longitude=" + lon
                    + "&latitude=" + lat);
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(object.toString());
            se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
            httppost.setEntity(se);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream is = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            JSONObject jso = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
            if (jso.getString("status").equals("ok")) {
                return 1;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return 0;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

i am getting below exception which is some time my logcat is below

```
   09-25 19:13:26.079: W/System.err(4842): org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
   09-25 19:13:26.079: W/System.err(4842):  at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:107)
   09-25 19:13:26.079: W/System.err(4842):  at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:158)
   09-25 19:13:26.079: W/System.err(4842):  at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
   09-25 19:13:26.079: W/System.err(4842):  at com.eheuristics.android.diegodeals.googleplacesandmaps.MainActivity$LoadPlaces.getResult(MainActivity.java:246)
   09-25 19:13:26.079: W/System.err(4842):  at com.eheuristics.android.diegodeals.googleplacesandmaps.MainActivity$LoadPlaces.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:208)
   09-25 19:13:26.079: W/System.err(4842):  at com.eheuristics.android.diegodeals.googleplacesandmaps.MainActivity$LoadPlaces.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
   09-25 19:13:26.079: W/System.err(4842):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
   09-25 19:13:26.079: W/System.err(4842):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
  09-25 19:13:26.089: W/System.err(4842):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
   09-25 19:13:26.089: W/System.err(4842):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
   09-25 19:13:26.089: W/System.err(4842):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
  09-25 19:13:26.089: W/System.err(4842):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Comment: Can you give us the result before building the JSON? Looks like it is a HTML page.

Comment: Not that BAD question to award him negatives!!!
Server is on other side of the developer and a developer may be in nascent stage!!

Comment: thanks user1931595 :( for your positive reply thanks you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your server sends you responses in html sometimes, not json.

Comment: Ya Peter DeWeese and boulder you both are right error is comming from server

Comment: Do not know why such people give negative marking (down vote) this question :( i have tried so much but do not know that actually error is coming from server

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is an issue with the result.
You should try to print the result before building the `JSON` object.

If there is an error, somewhere and then for some reason the result is a HTML page, then you cannot build your `JSON`.

For this error, it looks like that the result is HTML because of `<!DOCTYPE` and not a JSON.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are handling the server-response as a JSON, which is the expected behavoiur by you. But in some case like server is down, error in request, server is busy... some one has defined an UncaughtException handler to instruct the user via some GUI that something went wrong, which is returned by the server sometimes.
if you are reading the server response somewhere you can actually copy it and try to run it in some HTML page viewer to get the exact server response....

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this error is coming for SDK level 25, but it's working fine for SDK level 23.